How to compare real-time physiological data between pre-defined time blocks
I have a set of physiological data (skin conductance, skin temperature, heart rate) for approx. 20 patients measured per second over approx. 8 to 10 minutes during a virtual reality exercise.
The data is grouped into the following blocks of time:

calibration (patients put on the VR glasses and technical equipment is checked/adjusted)
test (patients walk around one of four neutral virtual environments)
first intervention (patients are subjected to one or more stressors in the virtual environment)
second intervention (patients use a pre-learned coping strategy in the virtual environment).

I want to test for significant changes between the blocks: i.e. did the variables change significantly between the test and 1st intervention blocks, did the variables change significantly between the 1st and 2nd intervention blocks.

Is it better to compare the blocks of data by using means or percentage increase/decrease?
Is it better to calculate percentage increase/decrease based on baseline or previous block data?
Is a paired t-test appropriate, or are other tests better?


Welcome to Cross Validated! It would help if you could provide more information about the data and the comparisons that you want to perform. How many physiological variables did you measure? Were there different interventions, or just the same intervention repeated? If there were different interventions, were they always in the same order? How much did the variables change during each block of time? How did the calibration and test periods differ? Please provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Ok thanks, I updated the question :)

For your first question, it's not wise to work in percents or percentage changes. Frank Harrell summarizes the arguments against them in this post. It's best to work with the original data and compare levels of the outcome values as a function of treatment.
The answer to your second question depends more on your understanding of the subject matter than on statistical principles. Even if you are working in the original data scale and eschew working with percents, you still have to decide on the specific comparisons you want to make.
If you want to know whether the values during the "second intervention" differ from those during the "test" period, then you need to make that comparison. If you care whether the values during the "second intervention" differed from those during the "first intervention," then you need to make that comparison. From what you explained I don't see much point in using the values from the "calibration" period, but you might have a reason to do so based on your understanding of the subject matter.
It's possible to make all pairwise comparisons of values during the time blocks, but the more comparisons you perform the harder it is to find true differences once you take precautions against the multiple comparison problem. Think carefully about what you and your audience will be most interested in.
Third, there are generalizations of paired t-tests that would be appropriate here. It's important to take into account the fact that the same individuals were providing data for all 4 time blocks. That can lead to correlated outcomes that don't meet the usual assumptions of independent outcome values for statistical tests. A linear mixed model is one frequent choice. Generalized least squares might also be a good choice here.
You should think about whether and how to deal with changes over time. My answer so far was based on the idea that the outcomes were reasonably constant throughout each individual time block. Plot the data and see if that's a reasonable assumption. You might need to incorporate time explicitly as a predictor, for example with a regression spline. Or, based on your understanding of the subject matter, you might decide on a sub-period of each time block that  represents a steady state and restrict your analysis to those steady-state periods.
Finally, your design does have one potential problem if I understand it correctly. The "second intervention" differed from the "first intervention" not only in the pre-learned coping strategy but also in the sequence in time. There might be learning effects in responses to stressors that you won't be able to distinguish from the effect of the coping strategy unless you had some individuals who had both "intervention" periods without having been taught the coping strategy.
